# How to calculate returns and group by company

Tags: r

I have the following data frame, and try to calculate the returns for each company by using Delt(Adjusted). I have to group by company, so the returns are correct when the row switches to another company and another adjusted price.

I try this code:

```
stocks$returns <- stocks %>%
  group_by(Company) %>% 
  Delt(Adjusted)
```

but get "Error in Delt(., Adjusted) : object 'Adjusted' not found"

Can anyone help me?

```
             Open   High    Low  Close   Volume Adjusted Company
2021-03-01 690.11 719.00 685.05 718.43 27136200   718.43    TSLA
2021-03-02 718.28 721.11 685.00 686.44 23732200   686.44    TSLA
2021-03-03 687.99 700.70 651.71 653.20 30208000   653.20    TSLA
2021-03-04 655.80 668.45 600.00 621.44 65919500   621.44    TSLA
2021-03-05 626.06 627.84 539.49 597.95 89396500   597.95    TSLA
2021-03-08 600.55 620.13 558.79 563.00 51787000   563.00    TSLA

require(quantmod)
require(zoo)

# STOCK DATA.FRAME
TSLA <- as.data.frame(getSymbols.yahoo("TSLA", from="2021-03-01", verbose=F, auto.assign=F))
AAPL <- as.data.frame(getSymbols.yahoo("AAPL", from="2021-03-01", verbose=F, auto.assign=F))
MSFT <- as.data.frame(getSymbols.yahoo("MSFT", from="2021-03-01", verbose=F, auto.assign=F))


TSLA$Company <- c("TSLA")
AAPL$Company <- c("AAPL")
MSFT$Company <- c("MSFT")

TSLA$Country <- "CA"
AAPL$Country <- "US"
MSFT$Country <- "US"

TSLA$Return <- Delt(TSLA$TSLA.Adjusted)
AAPL$Return <- Delt(AAPL$AAPL.Adjusted)
MSFT$Return <- Delt(MSFT$MSFT.Adjusted)

colnames(TSLA) <- c("Open", "High", "Low", "Close", "Volume", "Adjusted", "Company")
colnames(AAPL) <- c("Open", "High", "Low", "Close", "Volume", "Adjusted", "Company")
colnames(MSFT) <- c("Open", "High", "Low", "Close", "Volume", "Adjusted", "Company")

stocks <- rbind(TSLA, AAPL, MSFT)
rm(AAPL,MSFT,TSLA)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use all functions in a pipe. If you want to calculate returns use either:

```
stocks %>%
  group_by(Company) %>% 
  summarize(Returns = Delt(Adjusted))
```

or:

```
stocks %>%
  group_by(Company) %>% 
  mutate(Returns = Delt(Adjusted))
```